# Laravel Lumen file upload with full path

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, remote-access, lumen

I am uploading the file :

```
if ($request->hasFile('cnicFrontUrl')) {
    $picName = $request->file('cnicFrontUrl')->getClientOriginalName();
    $picName = base_path() . uniqid() . $picName;
    $destinationPath = "uploads/user_files/cnic";
    $request->file('cnicFrontUrl')->move($destinationPath, $picName);
    $userDetails->cnicFrontUrl = $picName;
}
```

The file moves to the `project/public/uploads/user_files/cnic` successfully,

But the filename which goes also to the database have the remote server directory path like `/var/www/html/baseApi/5927bcb59ba4fcar.png`

**How can i be able to store the filename like `https://example.com/public/uploads/user_files/cnic/5927bcb59ba4fcar.png` so it can be use be only accessing the filename.**

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
$userDetails->cnicFrontUrl = $picName;
```

with

```
$userDetails->cnicFrontUrl = url("/public/uploads/user_files/cnic")."/".uniqid(). 
                                  $request->file('cnicFrontUrl')
                                          ->getClientOriginalName();
```

or

```
$userDetails->cnicFrontUrl = asset($destinationPath. "/" . uniqid() . 
                                   $request->file('cnicFrontUrl')
                                           ->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: @linktohref .... Okay it is saved, But a small problem, I cannot get the image from the url by pasting the url in browser, It gives me `{"message":"not_found"}`. I am using lumen ? apache document root is `project/public`.

Comment: @Yellow that's because you moved the uploaded file into a non-public directory.

Comment: @Alfa OP moved the file to `project/public/uploads/user_files/cnic` and the document root is `project/public` shouldn't that be the public directory?

Comment: My bad, it should.